# Return an array of strings after filtering #tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, tags

I was wondering if someone could provide me with a JavaScript RegEx statement to filter out the text out of all the #tags in the input box.

Scenario: I have a user input text box where users can enter multiple #tags. What I would like to do is have all the texts filtered out and stored in an array after removing the special characters and save it to the database by looping over the array.

Example: Input- #tag1, #tag2, #tag3...

Output: An array of [tag1, tag2, tag3...]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is a simple task. Are you having trouble with a Regex that you created already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply:

```
/(#\w+)+/gmi
```

And in your list of regex matches, you'll have all of the tags in an array. This expression only supports letters, numbers and underscores - simply adjust the `\w` if you want to extend or restrict the set of characters.

Here's a regex101 to play around with: https://regex101.com/r/pJ8vA4/2

The javascript would look something like:

```
var string = '#tag1, #tag2, #tag3 some other stuff #tag4';
var tags = string.match(/(#\w+)+/gmi);
tags = result.map(function(tag) { return tag.replace('#', '') });
console.log(tags);
```

Comment: @NewUser07 added a simply map function to remove # from the results as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a place to as for questions, not for someone to make you code. But I will still answer.

```
(\s?#[a-zA-Z0-9]+,?)+
```

-separated by an optional white-space and optional commas
-make sure to trim the white space off the beginning and end of the returned values (while looping)
-also remove the hash tag (1st character after trimming)
-link for your example https://regex101.com/r/rT2aC5/1

edit: also does not include special characters. Let me know if you need a special modification and I will do it real quick for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "#tag1, #tag2, #tag3";
var regex = new RegExp(/#(\w+),?\s?/gi);
var match = null;
var results = [];

while (match = regex.exec(input)){
     results.push(match[1]);
}
```

This will give you a results array that has: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]

Comment: Vote up if you find it useful :)